# Lead Ads Testing Tool - Server failure (102)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to get Facebook leadgen ad data.

1-)As seen below, facebook sends the data to me successfully and I receive it successfully.

[Successful Process img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Ru7.png)

2-)But the submissions I made on just this page do not come. What could be the reason for this?

[Failed Process img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEKno.png)

*But only the opinions I made on this page are not coming. What could be the reason for this?
Facebook doesn't even post. As seen in the picture, Server failure (102) information is displayed. What is the reason of this?

3-)The code I received the incoming data

Asp.Net Api Method

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] JsonData data)
    {
        try
        {
            dbmanager db = new dbmanager();
            db.Jsonkaydetv2(data);
            var entry = data.Entry.FirstOrDefault();
            var change = entry?.Changes.FirstOrDefault();
            if (change == null) return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            //Generate user access token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
            const string token = "XXXX";

            var leadUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{change.Value.LeadGenId}?access_token={token}";
            var formUrl = $"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/{change.Value.FormId}?access_token={token}";

            using (var httpClientLead = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await httpClientLead.GetStringAsync(formUrl);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                {
                    var jsonObjLead = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeadFormData>(response);
                    db.JsonkaydetLeadFormData(jsonObjLead);
                    //jsonObjLead.Name contains the lead ad name
                    //Jsonkaydet(jsonObjLead.Name+"x");

                    //If response is valid get the field data
                    using (var httpClientFields = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        var responseFields = await httpClientFields.GetStringAsync(leadUrl);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseFields))
                        {
                            var jsonObjFields =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LeadData(responseFields);
                            db.JsonkaydetLeadData(jsonObjFields);
                            //jsonObjFields.FieldData contains the field value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Jsonkaydet(ex.ToString());
            Trace.WriteLine($"Error-->{ex.Message}");
            Trace.WriteLine($"StackTrace-->{ex.StackTrace}");
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm stuck with the same issue. As far as I can tell, the server failure is not on web hook end as I see no incoming request from Facebook while testing this.

Comment: yes solved, but not with the method here, the API structure has changed. We reviewed the document from the very beginning and made it again.